# Delete elements from array by .splice()

Tags: javascript, массивы

Как я могу удалить элемент вложенного массива? Типа: `array[i][j]`, где `j` - удаляемый элемент.

```
remove: function (array, indexID, indexSMS) {
    let localArray = array;
    console.log('Local array: ', localArray[indexID].length);
        for(let i = 0; i < localArray[indexID].length; i++) {
            console.log('We are in loop:', i, localArray[i]);
            console.log('This is LocalArray: ', localArray[i]);
            console.log('This is Index: ', indexID);
            console.log(localArray[i] === indexID);
            if(i === indexID) {
                let buffer = localArray[i];
                console.log(buffer);
                for(let j = 0; j < buffer[indexSMS].length; j++) {
                    console.log('IndexID: ', indexID);
                    console.log('IndexSMS: ', indexSMS);
                    buffer[j].splice(j, 1);
                    j--;
                    console.log(buffer)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Входные данные: `array` - входной массив, `i` - это индекс массива, `j` - это индекс элемента в массиве 
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80408/discussion-on-question-by-eugene-starodubov-delete-elements-from-array-by-splic).

Answer (score 0):

```
...; i < localArray.length; ...
```

такая же ошибка и во внутреннем цикле.

Конечно, зачем нужны эти циклы - совершенно непонятно.

---

О, спасибо. Сейчас ТС примет этот ответ и моя репутация красиво округлится.

Comment: Не стоит поощрять лень ТС в описании вопроса, тем более правка условий не поможет тут.

Comment: @Grundy - спасибо большое за бесполезные ответы

Comment: @Igor - спасибо большое за бесполезные ответы

Comment: @EugeneStarodubov, приведи в порядок вопрос, и получишь полезный ответ.